# R Remove specific character followed by number in Street Address

Tags: r, gsub

I would like to remove the character 'A&B' in 1st string and character 'B' in 2nd string followed by a number from the following vector containing a large number of strings.

However, I would retain certain characters like N, S, E, W, NE, NW, SE, SW, North, South, East, West (which are directions).

Below is an example:

```
str <- c("852 A&B Sandpiper Drive",
         "313 B North Dogwood Avenue",
         "852 N Sandpiper Drive",
         "3212 NE Highway 22",
         "852 A B Sandpiper Drive")
```

Expected output is as follows:

```
str <- c("852 Sandpiper Drive",
         "313 North Dogwood Avenue",
         "852 N Sandpiper Drive",
         "3212 NE Highway 22",
         "852 Sandpiper Drive")
```

I was not really able to come up with a nice solution. I know that I have to use sub or gsub but I am only able to remove single-digit alphabets only after a number.

Has anyone got an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with word boundaries :

```
gsub('\\b(A&B|A|B)\\s+', '', str)

#[1] "852 Sandpiper Drive" "313 North Dogwood Avenue" "852 N Sandpiper Drive"   
#[4] "3212 NE Highway 22"   "852 Sandpiper Drive"
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, this works however this leaves a blank space. Below is another line I have added to remove extra space `gsub("\\s+",replacement = " ", str)`                                                       Do u suggest any other in the mainline itself to overcome this extra space issue.

Comment: @rsayam91 Updated the answer to remove whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove without leaving more than one whitespace character:

```
sub("\\b(A&B|A B|B)\\b\\s", "", str)
[1] "852 Sandpiper Drive"      "313 North Dogwood Avenue" "852 N Sandpiper Drive"    "3212 NE Highway 22"      
[5] "852 Sandpiper Drive"
```

`sub` is fine as there's only one match per string (otherwise `gsub` would be needed); `&` is not a metacharacter and hence doesn't need escaping

An alternative solution is by defining capturing groups and recalling them in backreferences:

```
sub("(^\\d+)([AB& ]*)([A-Z][a-z].*$)", "\\1 \\3", str)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, this addresses the issue of extra space, however it did not work for str[5], where it has two alphabets followed by a number.